# Textures changing in render but not in 3D View

Tags: texturing, uv

I've just textured a simple character that I've made, but then I saw that I could make the textures look better. So, I loaded the new image file. The strange thing is, if I set the texture on the material and then render, I see it rendered with the new one, but in 3D view I see it in the old way. And, if I shift+X button remove the old image, save, reload then charge the new one, and set the material, the rendering is always correct (as you can see on the right in the pic below) but in 3D view it's all white (on the left)! How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The textured view is a shortcut to see the texture mapping of the image in the UV editor window. I suppose your texture is applied to the material of your model: select the model, Tab into edit mode, select all vertices, open an UV editor window, close the image of the window (if present), load your texture.
In this way the texture is "attached" to the actual UV map and will be displayed in the 3D view.